# XSLT: pass value from one for-each match to the next

Tags: xslt, xpath, docbook

I'm using the following to match all `<section>`s with a revision attribute set. `<section>`can appear at many different levels of the document tree, always contained within `<chapter>`s.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//section[@revision]">
    <!-- Do one thing if this is the first section 
           matched in this chapter -->

    <!-- Do something else if this section is in the same 
           chapter as the last section matched -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

As the comments say, I need to make each `for-each` iteration aware of the chapter to which the **previous** matched section belonged. I know that `<xsl:variable>`s are actually static once set, and that `<xsl:param>` only applies to calling templates.

This being Docbook, I can retreive a section's chapter number with:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::chapter[1]" mode="label.markup" />
```

but I think it can be done with purely XPath.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I unterstood your requirements 100%, but…

```
<xsl:variable name="sections" select="//section[@revision]" />

<xsl:for-each select="$sections">
  <xsl:variable name="ThisPos" select="position()" />
  <xsl:variable name="PrevMatchedSection" select="$sections[$ThisPos - 1]" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="
      not($PrevMatchedSection)
      or
      generate-id($PrevMatchedSection/ancestor::chapter[1])
      !=
      generate-id(ancestor::chapter[1])
    ">
      <!-- Do one thing if this is the first section 
           matched in this chapter -->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <!-- Do something else if this section is in the same 
           chapter as the last section matched -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>  
</xsl:for-each>
```

However, I suspect this whole thing can be solved more elegantly with a `<xsl:template>` / `<xsl:apply-templates>` approach. But without seeing your input and expected output this is hard to say.

Comment: thanks, I'm working on this.  One thing, though:  your `sections` variable defined before the `for-each` is not available inside the `for-each` loop itself.  Easily fixed by just not using the constant, though.

Comment: Of course is the variable available inside the `<xsl:for-each>`. The only thing that was not right was the `[position() - 1]` predicate, which I have fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

position() will return your position within the current for-each iteration. The first iteration, IIRC, will return 0, so testing for "position()=0" will tell you if you are in the first iteration.

Comment: The iteration count doesn't matter; I need to pass the chapter number from one iteration to the next.